# Never use stored session in sqlmap

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I am trying to make sqlmap to avoid fetch data from stored session. How do I achieve that? I have performed sqlmap check once on a target and now that target is offline, I want sqlmap to just stop the checks if target is offline and even if target is online it should recheck it not just show the data from stored session.

```
python3 sqlmap.py --threads=5 -m /tmp/sql --batch --answers "already=N"
```

```
[12:39:54] [CRITICAL] unable to connect to the target URL ('Connection refused')
sqlmap resumed the following injection point(s) from stored session:
---
Parameter: id2 (GET)
    Type: boolean-based blind
    Title: AND boolean-based blind - WHERE or HAVING clause
    Payload: id2=1 AND 9749=9749

    Type: UNION query
    Title: Generic UNION query (NULL) - 2 columns
    Payload: id2=1 UNION ALL SELECT NULL,'qzvpq'||'GUyWfclrkLkxNLVAdYrBXilkXpGmcpZLkJplITTj'||'qqbbq'-- qdhG
```

Answer (score 9):

use `--flush-session`

sample:
`sqlmap --flush-session -u ....`

Comment: Did it for me, don't know why it had been downvoted...

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the fresh queries switch:

```
    --fresh-queries     Ignore query results stored in session file
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I am getting the same behaviour even if use it.